# sendReceive's Timeouts versus `spray.can.*` Config Settings

Tags: scala, timeout, spray

The `spray-can` [docs](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.2/spray-can/configuration/) comment on the `spray.can.server.*` and `spray.can.client.*` config settings:

```
spray.can.server { 
  # The time after which an idle connection will be automatically closed.
  # Set to `infinite` to completely disable idle connection timeouts.
  idle-timeout = 60 s

  # If a request hasn't been responded to after the time period set here
  # a `spray.http.Timedout` message will be sent to the timeout handler.
  # Set to `infinite` to completely disable request timeouts.
  request-timeout = 20 s

spray.can.client { 
  # The time after which an idle connection will be automatically closed.
  # Set to `infinite` to completely disable idle timeouts.
  idle-timeout = 60 s

  # The max time period that a client connection will be waiting for a response
  # before triggering a request timeout. The timer for this logic is not started
  # until the connection is actually in a state to receive the response, which
  # may be quite some time after the request has been received from the
  # application!
  # There are two main reasons to delay the start of the request timeout timer:
  # 1. On the host-level API with pipelining disabled:
  #    If the request cannot be sent immediately because all connections are
  #    currently busy with earlier requests it has to be queued until a
  #    connection becomes available.
  # 2. With pipelining enabled:
  #    The request timeout timer starts only once the response for the
  #    preceding request on the connection has arrived.
  # Set to `infinite` to completely disable request timeouts.
  request-timeout = 20 s
```

However, I also see that there's an `implicit` `Timeout` that can be passed to [sendReceive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958936/akka-timeout-when-using-spray-client-for-multiple-request#comment42457273_26958936).

Does setting any of the above config values result in a clash/override of the `implicit` `Timeout`? In short, I'm trying to understand the distinction between `sendReceive`'s implicit time-out and the above config values.